# Embedded Groovy in Java application:

Tags: java, groovy

I have an application (using Java 8) that uses Groovy scripts in an embedded way like this:

```
            GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader();
            Class calcClass = gcl.parseClass(myclass);
            GroovyObject calc = (GroovyObject) calcClass.newInstance();
            return (String) calc.invokeMethod("evaluateScript", new Object[]{});
```

This has been working really well.

I recently upgraded to Java 17 and that same logic generates the exception below:

```
Unable to evaluate smart template script: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator java.text.Format.createAttributedCharacterIterator(java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator[]) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.text" to unnamed module @4ec24700
```

I am using SimpleDateFormat from java.text and the script does not seem to be allowed to access classes in this package.

Is there any way I can get this to work? The Groovy docs (https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/guide-integrating.html) do not mention anything about Java modules or thelike.

Thanks!

Update: Adding the code that is called within the script:

```
    String FRIST(String fromDate, String addDays, String format) {
        if(fromDate==null || "".equals(fromDate))
            return "??.??.????";
        
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat df=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        try {
            java.util.Date testDate = df.parse(fromDate)
            java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(); 
            cal.setTime(testDate);
            if(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) < 2000)
                cal.add(java.util.Calendar.YEAR, 2000);
            cal.add(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(addDays));
            testDate = cal.getTime();
            if(format==null) {
                return df.format(testDate);
            } else {
                return new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(format).format(testDate);
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            return "??.??.????"
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: You're trying to call a non-public method (there's no public `createAttributedCharacterIterator`). Groovy lets you do this "accidentally" (i.e. there's no different syntax for public vs non-public methods). Java >= 9 is stricted about access control, specifically when touch classes that aren't yours.

Comment: @JoachimSauer thank you for the reply. I understand what you're saying, but I cannot make sense out of it related to the code in my script. I updated the question to include the code snippet and it does not call any non-public methods. 

The full stacktrace can be found here: https://github.com/jlawyerorg/j-lawyer-org/issues/2237

And the line that raises the exception is

java.text.SimpleDateFormat df=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

Seems weird to me.

Comment: What version of Groovy are you using?

Comment: stacktrace is saying  `at SmartTemplate.FRIST(script17028897605991054134770.groovy:163)` - what's in line 163?

Comment: Have you tried with `--add-opens java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED` ? On a side-note, with java.time and actually writing Groovy, this could be condensed quite a bit; and format is ignored in the two error branches.

Comment: I have tried something similar with Groovy 3.0.19 and 4.0.16 and I am able to perform `new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(date)` in Groovy from Java 17 without a problem.

Comment: my guess it's connected with context switching between groovy-java. class is compiled by groovy but executed by java under different classloader...

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(date)` shouldn't trigger that exception at all. Have you double- and tripple-checked that that's actually the code at line 163 of your groovy script? Because I suspect that some calling into other methods / calling of template methods of some kind happens here and you're following a red herring. Also, there's a good chance that you simply must update your version of the Groovy libraries to be compatible with the Java version you're now running.

Comment: Thanks everyone, you have pointed in the right direction. I upgraded to Groovy 4.0.16 and it's working again.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be fixed by upgrading to the latest Groovy stable version (4.0.16 at the time of this writing).

Credits to the commenters above, and specifically to @david-conrad for the  specific suggestion to upgrade Groovy.